# Apple ad hoc distribution issue

Tags: ios

I am trying to deploy an app using the ad hoc method on iOS devices (iPhones). We created a developer account and invited my apple account to join the development team. I managed to setup a provisioning profile and use it in Xcode to build an ad hoc archive.

We uploaded the archive to an URL (the one set in the manifest) and set up a simple install app using href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://..".

The issue I have now is that this works OK for the device I used before during development (iOS 12 iPhone 6), but cannot run the ad hoc app on a second device (iOS 14 iPhone 7), even though I added both devices' UUID to my account. The app installs on the second device but gives the "identity cannot be verified" message when trying to run it.

So in short, I managed to do an ad hoc install only on the device I started developing on - the one that is logged in with my account (not the main developer account that invited me to join the developer team).

I would really appreciate some help - as for me, Apple's overall approach is confusing and messy at this point and there are few replies related to this specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> even though i added both device UUID to my account

It isn't enough to add another device to the account. An ad hoc build contains a provisioning profile that explicitly lists all the devices it can run on. That profile is not magically self updating. You have to
re-export from the archive with a new provisioning profile that includes the new device.

Comment: Also if you've just got two people, over the air installation is overkill. Just export the build from the archive and email it to your friend.

Comment: Yes, making a new Profile was not clear , while i rebuilt the Archive each time I used 1 profile I generated before adding more devices thinking apple automatically included all devices from the device list in the build , thank you for this quick and spot on answer . Also the long term target for this is to be able to distribute the app to a 3rd party using a simple link/url.